# SQL Server: breaking a multiple join query into smaller ones and creating a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a complex query with multiple joins in it, which runs multiple times in my application. I want to write this query as a function by breaking this query into smaller pieces inside the function. As a newbie, I have limited knowledge on SQL Server.

The following is the query:

```
SELECT 
     ts.lable as label,
     ts.percentage as rate
FROM 
     TaxSet ts 
JOIN 
     UserInfo u ON u.userID = ? 
                AND u.countryID = ts.countryId 
                AND (ts.stateId IS NULL OR ts.stateId = 0 OR LEN(ts.stateId) < 1)
JOIN
     Users us ON u.userID = us.id
JOIN
     Users p ON us.parentID = p.id
             AND ts.ispID = p.id
JOIN
     ProductType pt ON ts.productTypeID = pt.id
WHERE 
     startDate <= getutcdate() 
     AND getutcdate() <= endDate 
     AND pt.identifier = ?
     AND ts.id NOT IN (SELECT eu.ispTaxSettingId 
                       FROM ExemptUsers eu 
                       WHERE eu.ExemptUserId = ?)
```

Now, how can I write a function by breaking this query into smaller ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I want to write this query as a function by breaking this query into smaller pieces inside the function"* - **Why?** What do you expect this to achieve?

Comment: @GarethD:This query is running from the php code, I've another query similar to this with only one condition changed in it,As this is taking much time to give results, I was asked to break down this query by using some temp tables in a function to make the joins easier, so that it will not take much time.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: No, this is the complete query.

Comment: Breaking this query into multiple steps will NOT make it quicker. You might want to check to see whether the columns involved in the joins are suitably indexed.

Comment: @RhysJones: The first thing I did is that, the columns involved in this query have indexes on them.

Comment: To which table belong startDate  and endDate? And what data type is stateId?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: startdate and enddate,stateid(bigint) all are related to tasxet table.

Comment: Thanks. So why do you join ProductType? Is this supposed to be a check for its existence?  So with a particular user you are looking for taxsets belonging to his *parent user* where the user himself happens to have a user info for the same country and a certain product type is related to that taxset. That sounds weird. Are you sure the query does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: yes, ProductType is for checking the existence and yes, the query is giving the result as expected (though the query is not written by me)

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you want to split it into functions? I reformatted your code and have put it into a stored procedure for now. My thinking is that you want to pass through a Identifier and UserID which are the parameters of your query.

I have modified the query and removed the Not In statement. This has been replaced by a LEFT JOIN to ExemptUsers on u.id = eu.ExemptUserID and then an addition to the WHERE clause to ensure eu.ExemptUserID is NULL. This is basically a clearer way of saying "If the userID exists in table ExemptUsers do not bring back results for that user".

In addition I have removed the join to Users p as I can't see that this was being used in any way, unless you want to ensure that the user has a parent?

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE wsp_StoredProcName 
(@UserID int,
@Identifier int)

AS

BEGIN


    SELECT 
        ts.lable as label,
        ts.percentage as rate
    FROM 
         TaxSet ts 
            INNER JOIN UserInfo u ON u.userID = ts.UserID 
                AND u.countryID = ts.countryId  
            INNER JOIN Users us on u.userID = us.id
            INNER JOIN ProductType pt on ts.productTypeID = pt.id
            LEFT JOIN ExemptUsers eu on u.id = eu.ExemptUserID
    WHERE 
         (
            ts.UserID = @UserID
            and pt.identifier = @Identifier
            and startDate <= getutcdate() 
            and getutcdate() <= endDate 
            AND eu.ExemptUserID IS NULL
            and 
            (
            ts.stateId is null or ts.stateId = 0 or len(ts.stateId) < 1
            )
        )

END
```

Comment: FYI, using [`NOT EXISTS` is a better option in SQL Server than `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL`](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/). The SQL Server optimiser is able to use an anti-semi join with not exists, but left join cannot make this optimization. Also the join to `ExemptUsers` should also include `ts.id = eu.ispTaxSettingId`

Comment: @GarethD: yes, u r right gareth, I added that and checked it, It is giving me the results but may I know is this the better approach than my original query in case of performance (parden me., I don't know much regarding these issues).

Comment: @Hazkirby: thanks for this, I made some modifications and made it work in your way.

Comment: Also, assuming that `st.stateId` is an integer, you can change this part - `(ts.stateId is null or ts.stateId = 0 or len(ts.stateId) < 1)` to `ISNULL(ts.StateID, 0) BETWEEN -9 AND 9`, it is both more concise, and since it removes `LEN(ts.stateId)`, which is stopping any index on `stateid` being used, it will perform better.

Answer (score 1):

After all you select from TaxSet where certain conditions must be met: The date range, the state, a relation to a particular user and its parent, a relation to a particular product type, and the non-existence for a particular exempt user. So use EXISTS and NOT EXISTS throughout your query in order to make it plain to the reader and dbms what you want to achieve. The more straight-forward a query, the easier it often is for the optimizer to deal with it.

```
select 
  ts.lable as label,
  ts.percentage as rate
from taxset ts 
where getutcdate() between ts.startdate and ts.enddate 
and (stateid is null or stateid between 0 and 9)
and exists 
(
  select *
  from users u
  join userinfo ui on ui.userid = u.id
  where u.id = ?
  and ui.countryid = ts.countryid
  and u.parentid = ts.ispid
)
and exists
(
  select * 
  from producttype pt 
  where pt.identifier = ?
  and pt.id = ts.producttypeid
)
and not exists
(
  select *
  from exemptusers eu 
  where eu.exemptuserid = ?
  and eu.isptaxsettingid = ts.id
);
```

As others have mentioned: When splitting a query into smaller parts and execute these separately, it usually becomes slower not faster. This is due to the fact that a dbms is made to do exactly this in the most efficient way internally. Of course sometimes a dbms' optimizer fails to find a good execution plan, though. You may want to look at the execution plan and check whether you find that plan appropriate.